Hyperlink for subsection in table of content
I wanted to create subsection with "Exercise" labelled at the front, and this is what I did
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={7in, 10in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages,pdflscape,titlesec}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[upint]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\titleformat
{\section} % command
{\bfseries\LARGE} % format
{Section \thesection:} % label
{0.5ex} % sep
{\vspace{1ex}\centering} % before-code
{\vspace{1ex}\centering} % after-code

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{Exercise \thesection.\arabic{subsection}.}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{This is section one}

\subsection{}

Something about exercise 1.1

\subsection{}

Something about exercise 1.2

\subsection{}

Something about exercise 1.3

\end{document}

Everything works out well, except that in the table of contents, the box for the hyperlink to each subsection is too small that the dots are overlapping with the word "Exercise 1.1".

Is there a way to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Adding names to \thesubsection is not always a good approach. Try adding \setlength\overfullrule{5pt} to your doc and you'll see what is going on. Hint there is not enough room in the number box to fix the entire text.

The default classes does not really provide a good interface to change this but you can use \usepackage{tocloft}\setlength\cftsubsecnumwidth{2.5cm}

Welcome to TeX.SE!
